# Is there a way [VBA] to check in a for each loop if the looping cell is = to the previous?

Tags: excel, vba, range, cell

What i want is to look if the cell.value that increments, after the loop, is equals to itself but of precedent cicle.

```
If Not Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then
  risorsa = Cells(Target.ROW, 3).Value
  For Each cell In rngCalendario 
    If UCase(cell.Value) Like "*" & risorsa & "*" Then '
      For i = cell.ROW To RigaNomeProgetto Step -1 
        If Cells(i, 2).Value = 0 And cell.ROW < ultimaRiga Then 
          NomeProgetto = Cells(i, 1).Value 
          Exit For
        End If
      Next i
      Output = LTrim(Output) & NomeProgetto & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & Chr(10)  
    End If
  Next cell
  Cells(2, 4) = Output
End if
```

Comment: There is a way, but you need to provide more information on where you want to check for it. Depending on inside which `For` loop you want the check to happen.

Comment: *Yes* there is a way. It will depend on your `Target` range. Is it n x 1, 1 x n, or n x n? This will determine how you check the "previous" cell, ie. `.Offset(-1,0)` for row and `.Offset(0,-1)` for column...

Comment: @M.Schalk I want to do in For Each cell In rngCalendario, and the if statement under it would be something like : 

If UCase(cell.Value) Like "*" & risorsa & "*" And prevCell.value <> cell.value then
  do stuff
  prevCell = cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
    If Not Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then

    Dim prevCell As Variant 'Choose applicable type, probably String
    risorsa = Cells(Target.Row, 3).Value

    For Each cell In rngCalendario
      If UCase(cell.Value) Like "*" & risorsa & "*" And prevCell = cell.Value Then 'current cell value is compared to previous cell
        For i = cell.Row To RigaNomeProgetto Step -1
          If Cells(i, 2).Value = 0 And cell.Row < ultimaRiga Then
            NomeProgetto = Cells(i, 1).Value
            Exit For
          End If
        Next i
        Output = LTrim(Output) & NomeProgetto & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & Chr(10)
      End If
      prevCell = cell.Value 'prevCell is assigned the value of the current cell
    Next cell
    Cells(2, 4) = Output
End If
```